# How to set Google Chrome's fonts for different languages?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

For example, this is the source code of a test page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div lang="en-US">Test.</div>
        <div lang="zh-CN">Test.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If Google Chrome's display language is English, the second line's font is SimSun even I set the browser's sans-serif font to Microsoft YaHei. It only works for the language that your browser uses. Is it possible to set the browser's font for different languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Chrome provides several APIs to help people write extensions to do so: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fontSettings.html.